# I'm building a chrome extension that needs to get the URL of the page, but it is getting the URL of the chrome extension, not the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and it needs to get the URL of a page and write it on the popup, but instead of doing that, it writes this: chrome-extension://extension-id/popup.html. I want it to say this instead: https://url.tld/url-path.ext. Here is my manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Browser History Recorder",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    }
}
```

Here is my popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="text">
</body>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
setTimeout(record,1);
function record() {
   document.write(window.location.href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The popup is sandboxed from parent/host page, meaning you cannot access anything from that page directly, but you use *message passing* to communicate between parent page and your popup. You can include a content script to run in the page that will handle one end of the message passing. Read more about [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) here.

In your manifest.json

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<your site pattern here>"],
      "js": ["inject.js"] // this will run in the parent page.
    }
  ]
```

In `inject.js`, you can listen for a message from the popup.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // handle the request from popup and send a response by invoking the callback that was passed
  sendResponse(window.location.href)
});
```

And from somewhere in the JS running in your popup, you can send your message.

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {}, (href) => {
    // here is where you'll have your URL from the parent page.
    console.log(href)
  })
});
```

Read more about message passing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) in the Google docs.

Comment: I added that code, saved it, and reloaded the extension. Nothing changed.

Comment: This is not meant to be a fully working example. You'll need to go read through the docs and make sure you have everything hooked up correctly. What I'm showing you here is that you cannot simply access the parent page's URL via `window.location.href` from the popup. You have to tell Chrome, when running your extension, to inject a JS file into the parent page, and then use message passing to communicate between that script and your popup. It's up to you to either ask more specific questions, provide more context, or continue researching and debugging.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the chrome.runtime.getURL or chrome.extension.getURL?

Comment: One of those is deprecated, but those don't do what you want them to do. From the docs " Converts a relative path within an app/extension install directory to a fully-qualified URL." That's not going to help you get the URL of the parent page the user has open.

Comment: I think its getting closer to working, but in the chrome extensions page it now shows the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Matthew Brooks, you need a content script.
You can try this:

First, add `activeTab` to `permissions` in **manifest.json**.

**manifest.json**

```
...
"permissions": ["activeTab"],
...
```

Then, in your popup code, you can do:

```
setTimeout(record, 1);
function record() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:'return window.location.href'}, result => {
        document.getElementById('text').textContent = result[0];  //result will be an array
    });
}
```